# Does Resist All apply to different damage types from the same or different sources?

Tags: dnd-4e, disease

Here's the scenario: A PC is infected with the initial stage of Black Boils. A disease which causes small acid filled pustules to form under the skin. The initial stage says "Whenever that target takes damage it takes 1 additional point of damage."

Now this PC (a paladin btw) was buffed on the attack and damage by a nearby artificer with Shocking Feedback. What I want to know, for future, is does Shocking Feedback's Resistance buff apply to both the attack's damage and the disease's damage separately or does it only function on the total attack damage as a whole?

Answer (score 4):

The key is in the wording:

> "Whenever that target takes damage it takes 1 **additional** point of damage."

This means it's extra damage added to the initial source of damage. Pretty much all sources of extra damage work this way. (Sneak Attack, Curse damage, Quarry, etc)

So you first calculate the total damage of the attack (original damage + 1) and then apply Resistance to that amount.